# Wrong PHP parsing order in snippet

Tags: php, snippets, parse

I'm trying to parse a global variable inside a snippet that represents my page footer, and I want to perform a string function on the content of that variable.
The snippet is being called into a template with PHP parsing ON and set to OUTPUT.
This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
<?php echo trim(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\r"), ', ', "{address}")); ?>
```

The value of the variable is (for example):

```
Big Company
Main Street
Big Town
```

And I want it to be:

```
Big Company, Main Street, Big Town
```

But PHP is trying to modify the string "{address}" not the actual value of the address variable, so I just end up with the original content (address with line breaks) when the EE parses the result of that function which is {address} in the template.

What am I doing wrong?

EE 2.6.1

Comment: I'm guessing that this is because snippets are parsed so early in the template, so what's the alternative? It didn't seem to work in an embedded template either :(

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch that global variable like:

```
$address = ee()->db->select('variable_data')->where('variable_name', 'address')->get('global_variables')->row('variable_data');
echo trim(str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\r"), ', ', $address));
```

It would work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid a direct hack like this but it would be the quickest temporary solution, thanks.

Comment: I don't think its hack ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because user-defined global variables are parsed very late - after PHP on input, after all module and plugin tags, and even after PHP on output ([see parse order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages)).

Your best bet here is to write a simple plugin which fetches the global variable directly from the database, does its work, then returns it.

Comment: Sounds handy, a little surprised it needs a workaround though.